# Is possible to load as a src= .. a link put on a previous a href=?

Tags: html, iframe, href, preview, src

I have a numerous links enlisted in various tables in my web, those have a preview in an iframe that open as a popup, this works all well, but it will be more easy if I put the link only one time and not necessary to repeat on iframe, the links are written as follow:

```
<td>
<a href="LINK1.html" target="_blank"><img class="imageg" src="img/timon2.png"></a>
        <div class="boxht cint">
          <iframe src="LINK1.html" width = "100%" height = "100%" frameBorder="0" ></iframe>
        </div>
</td>
...
<td>
<a href="LINK2.html" target="_blank"><img class="imageg" src="img/timon2.png"></a>
        <div class="boxht cint">
          <iframe src="LINK2.html" width = "100%" height = "100%" frameBorder="0" ></iframe>
        </div>
</td>
```

Here is the original page with the iframe that is popped up when the mouse pass over the rotating rudder:
http://emmind.net/endogenous_fields_&_mind.html.
The next lines are the part of the code that refer to the iframe and its effects if it can be helpful:

**Rotating rudder:**

```
.imageg {
    position: static;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: -0px 0 0 -0px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 8.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 8.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 8.5s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

**The `div` containing the `iframe`:**

```
.boxht {
    display: none;
    width: 35%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16%;
    left: 63%;
    height: 65%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #ffffbb;
}
a:hover + .boxht {
    display: inline;
}
.boxht:hover {
    display: inline;
}
```

**Effect of stones overlapping the frame:**

```
.cint:before,
.cint:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.cint:before {
    bottom: -40px;
    left: -30px;
    height: 79px;
    width: 85px;
    background-image: url(img/piedra2c.png);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
.cint:after {
    top: -42px;
    right: -20px;
    width: 93px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(img/piedra1.png);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use Javascript or jQuery to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quickly done with jQuery (even though it's arguable whether one should actually use it for this task being it not very complicated).
Embed a version of jQuery in your header via the `<script src>` tag, and you can use this snippet.
As a reference you can look up the [API docs of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/).

```js
// Perform `function` when the page loads
$(function() {
  // Select all `img` tags with class `imageg` that are children of an `a`
  $('a > img.imageg').each(function(i) {
    // Wrap the parent (`a`) into jQuery
    var $href = $(this.parentNode);
    // Generate a new div > iframe and insert it after `a`
    $('<div class="boxht cint"><iframe src="' + $href.attr('href') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>').insertAfter($href);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="LINK1.html" target="_blank">
        <img class="imageg" src="img/timon2.png">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="LINK2.html" target="_blank">
        <img class="imageg" src="img/timon2.png">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, some principles of the idea works, the code take the previous ahref and put it in the generated next line. But it not display it respecting the display type that I have put in different styles. (and load the iframe content in spite of don't do a hover)

Better it can ve seen what is the error visually:

Here is the original page with the iframe that is popped up when the mouse pass over the rotating rudder:
http://emmind.net/endogenous_fields_&_mind.html
And here what happening when I added the code above:
http://emmind.net/endogenous_fields_&_mindPROBE.html

Comment: @P.A.Munduate It's a typo. Both question and answer use a `div` with class `boxht2` instead of `boxht`, which is the class in your original page.

Comment: Yes it works!, now I can devote to remove a lot of lines of code that surplus, good! Thanks

Comment: @P.A.Munduate Then you may consider marking the answer as accepted if it solves your issue?